# express-validator - Customize errors output

Tags: node.js, error-handling, lodash, express-validator

I am using express validator to validate the json body.

#### router

```
router.post('/login', [
  body('mobno')
    .exists().withMessage('Required')
    .isLength({ min: 10, max: 12 }).withMessage('10-12 characters')
    .isNumeric().withMessage('Numeric'),
  body('password')
    .not().isEmpty().withMessage('Password is required'),
], async (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.json({ errors: errors.array(), success: false, msg: 'Check Parameters' });
  }
 // do stuff and respond
});
```

#### response

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "value": "998716***658()",
      "msg": "10-12 characters",
      "param": "mobno",
      "location": "body"
    },
    {
      "value": "998716***658()",
      "msg": "Numeric",
      "param": "mobno",
      "location": "body"
    }
  ],
  "success": false,
  "msg": "Check Parameters"
}
```

In the frontend, I am using Vuetify, hence I need the resonse to be in a format which can easily be consumed by the frontend.

#### Expected output

```
{
  "errors": {
    "mobno": [
      "10-12 characters",
      "Numeric"
    ]
  },
  "success": false,
  "msg": "Check Parameters"
}
```

### Question

1. Is there any option/function which I can hook into which will format the `errors` in the way I want it.
2. I am thinking to use Lodash for this transformation, any suggestions on how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lodash chain to group the errors by the `param`, and then map the items in each group to the `msg` property. Then you can combine the `errors` object with the previous result using object spread.

```js
const data = {"errors":[{"value":"998716***658()","msg":"10-12 characters","param":"mobno","location":"body"},{"value":"998716***658()","msg":"Numeric","param":"mobno","location":"body"}],"success":false,"msg":"Check Parameters"}

const errors = _(data.errors)
  .groupBy('param')
  .mapValues(group => _.map(group, 'msg'))
  .value()
  
const result = {
  ...data,
  errors
}

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.14/lodash.js"></script>
```

And a pipeline approach using lodash/fp and `_.flow()`:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, mapValues, map } = _

const transform = flow(
  groupBy('param'),
  mapValues(map('msg'))
)

const data = {"errors":[{"value":"998716***658()","msg":"10-12 characters","param":"mobno","location":"body"},{"value":"998716***658()","msg":"Numeric","param":"mobno","location":"body"}],"success":false,"msg":"Check Parameters"}
  
const result = {
  ...data,
  errors: transform(data.errors)
}

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```